# Spring AMQP and CompositeConnectionListener

Tags: spring-amqp

I have a class that extends from CompositeConnectionListener, and I have a bean defined like this:

```
@Bean 
public CompositeConnectionListener connectionListener(){
    return new MyCompositeConnectionListener();
}

public class MyCompositeConnectionListener extends CompositeConnectionListener
{

        @Override
        public void onClose(Connection conn) 
        {
          .....

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Connection arg0) 
        {   
          .....
}
```

If I close the connection (for example from the rabbitmq management), the bean is working OK (I can detect the onClose and the onCreate methods). But, If I do it again (I close the connection one more time), the onclose method is not working, only the onCreate method. I'm trying to figure out what happens but for now do not get to know why.

Thanks

I use this class just to see the error message when the connection goes down. Inside the method onClose and onCreage I have nothing really interesting :

```
@Override
    public void onClose(Connection conn) 
    {
        System.err.println("-------------- onClose(Connection conn) --------------");
        super.onClose(conn);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Connection arg0) 
    {       
        try {
            System.err.println("-------------- onCreate(Connection arg0)  --------------");
            super.onCreate(arg0);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.error("Error.", ex);
        }
    }
```

And this is my logs:

```
Error connecting to the server: Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
Error connecting to the server: Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
Error connecting to the server: Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.144] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Error connecting to the server: Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.144] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.145] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Error connecting to the server: Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.145] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.145] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Error connecting to the server: Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.145] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
Error connecting to the server: Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.892] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Error connecting to the server: Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.891] WARN  - DSISOFT3 - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:723)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:713)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:666)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:620)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error connecting to the server: Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.893] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Error connecting to the server: Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
 Error (ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent): Consumer raised exception, attempting restart
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.893] WARN  - DSISOFT3 - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:723)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:713)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:666)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:620)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Error (ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent): Consumer raised exception, attempting restart
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.893] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Error conectando AMQP : connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:723)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:713)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:666)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:620)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.894] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Excepcion capturada conectando AMQP : connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:723)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:713)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:666)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:620)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.894] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Excepcion capturada Con excepcion : com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.894] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Error conectando AMQP : connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:723)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:713)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:666)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:620)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.894] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Excepcion capturada conectando AMQP : connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:723)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:713)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:666)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:620)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.895] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Excepcion capturada Con excepcion : com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
Error connecting to the server: Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.900] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Error connecting to the server: Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.900] WARN  - DSISOFT3 - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:723)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:713)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:666)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:620)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Error (ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent): Consumer raised exception, attempting restart
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.900] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Error conectando AMQP : connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:723)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:713)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:666)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:620)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.901] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Excepcion capturada conectando AMQP : connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:723)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:713)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:666)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:620)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[06/06/2016 17:47:11.901] ERROR - DSISOFT3 - Excepcion capturada Con excepcion : com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - Closed via management plugin, class-id=0, method-id=0)
-------------- onClose(Connection conn) --------------
-------------- onCreate(Connection arg0)  --------------
```

The second time the onClose method is not been called.

Comment: It would be great to see how you use this class. Plus, share some DEBUG logs for `org.springframework.amqp` category when the close happens.